# How can I send multi response data using Netty?(Part-2)

Tags: netty

I posted a question with the same title before,and after that, I improved it,but a new problem occurred,so I will post it as another question.
I want to return multiple response data to a client on a server using Netty(4.1.51). According to our specifications, the first response data is in the format of HttpHeader and body, abd the second and subsequent data must return just byte array or string data. I'm coding the follow code, but I'm executing the writeAndFlush() method in channelContext, but it's not received on the client side. Our client program can receive it by ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE, but we can still receive connected some data.

What I expected ,

[Client side]  bfIn.recvLine();…1st wait
[Server side] chlCtx.writeAndFlush(firstData);
[Client side]  (received firstData)
[Client side]  bfIn.recvLine();…2nd wait
[Server side] chlCtx.writeAndFlush(secondData);
[Client side]  (received secondData)
[Client side]  bfIn.recvLine();…3rd wait
[Server side] chlCtx.writeAndFlush(thirdData);
[Client side]  (received thirdData)
[Server side] chlFuture.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE)

The actual behavior of the system is as follows,

[Client side]  bfIn.recvLine();…1st wait
[Server side] chlCtx.writeAndFlush(firstData);
[Client side] ...continue 1st wait
[Server side] chlCtx.writeAndFlush(secondData);
[Client side] ...continue 1st wait
[Server side] chlCtx.writeAndFlush(thirdData);
[Client side] ...continue 1st wait
[Server side] chlFuture.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE)
[Client side]  (received connected data - first & second & third - )

What am I missing ? Or is it wrong?

#### Server side

```
ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
 .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
 .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ch.pipeline().addLast(new ChannelHandler());
        //    :


public class ChannelHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<byte[]> {
    public void channelRead(ChannelContext chlCtx, Object msg) {
        byte[] firstData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] secondData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] thirdData = new byte[512];
        //    :
        byte[] response = Unpooled.buffer(firstData.length);
        response.writeBytes(firstData);
        ChannelFuture chlFuture = chlCtx.writeAndFlush(response);
        if (chlFuture.cause() != null){
            chlFuture.cause().printStackTrace();
        }
        // No error
        // Client program is no received data.

        response = Unpooled.buffer(secondData.length);
        response.writeBytes(secondData);
        chlFuture = chlCtx.writeAndFlush(response);
        if (chlFuture.cause() != null){
        chlFuture.cause().printStackTrace();
        }
        // No error
        // Client program is no received data.

        response = Unpooled.buffer(thirdData.length);
        response.writeBytes(thirdData);
        chlFuture = chlCtx.writeAndFlush(response);
        if (chlFuture.cause() != null){
            chlFuture.cause().printStackTrace();
        }
        // No error
        // Client program is no received data.
        //    :
        chlFuture.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        // Client program is received first&second&third data.
        //    :

}
```

#### Client side

```
Socket chl = new Socket();
//    :
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(chl.getInputStream()));
while (true){
    while ((recv = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(recv);
    }
    if (recv.substring(0,4).equals("LAST"){
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should attach a `ChannelFutureListener` to the `ChannelFuture` to see if the writes fails. Remember everything is non-blocking which means the write may only happen at some point so you can't just assume it is done once the future is returned.

```
ChannelFuture future = ...;
future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() { ...});
```